# can't get lato fonts to work in texlive 2011

Tags: fonts, errors

This is my first post - so I hope you can help me; and I haven't missed anything obvious. I am interested in using Lato fonts an am using texlive 2011 on Windows 7.

My minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

However, pdf fails to compile with the following error message. I have failed to find the underlying problem (I don't have problems with any other fonts) and thought I'd ask the experts!

Compile messages:

```
! I can't find file `Labegin.mf'.
<scantokens> input Labegin.mf

<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.185 ...onteq-2,fonteq) of jobname & "begin.mf");

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<scantokens> input Labegin.mf

<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.185 ...onteq-2,fonteq) of jobname & "begin.mf");

Transcript written on Lato-Reg-01.log.

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Labegin.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32\mktexmf
mf-nowin.exe --progname=mf --base=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=1+0/600; nonstopmode; input Lato-Reg-01;
Failed to make gf font by METAFONT.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file Lato-Reg-01): Font Lato-Reg-01 at 600 not fou
nd
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 Lato-Reg-01

The command name is C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32\mktexpk
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks).

Comment: Are you sure to have a full install of TeX Live 2011?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell everything has been installed and access to other fonts is OK.  However, if others can use Lato fonts in texlive in 2011 it would suggest a local problem...so I will see if I can trace anything obvious that is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your mapfile `pdftex.map` is somehow not up to date. Maybe you are using a private version?

```
kpsewhich pdftex.map
```

should give something like

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

Just in case, you could try to add

```
\pdfmapfile{+lato.map}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Ah - that might be it.  I get:

Comment: `\pdfmapfile{+lato.map}` seems preferable; without the `+` the default map file wouldn't be read in. Also `=lato.map` might be, but it's quite improbable that it contains fonts already loaded in `pdftex.map`.

Comment: Ah - that might be it.  I get:
c:/Users/david/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map

and adding \pdfmapfile{lato.map} does work! So that gives me something to work on. The pdftex.map in that location is indeed out of date and the file in C:\texlive\2011\texmf-var\fonts\map\pdftex\updmap is up to date. Some path problem...

(as an aside - I'm amazed by this site and the quality and rapidity of the help offered - excellent!)

Comment: I was getting a missfonts.log file with a similar error to the above, and the `kpsewhich` command helped me find a workaround, so thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I get the error too (I'm using miktex). At least on miktex the reason is that the map file has not been activated during the installation. You can load it manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pdfmapfile{=lato.map}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```